# If $z=2(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)$, use the triangle inequality to find an upper estimate for $|e^{z^2} + 4\sin(z)|$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

> If $z=2(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)$ ($0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$), use the triangle inequality to find an upper estimate for $|e^{z^2} + 4\sin(z)|$.

Okay so if I write $z$ in the form $x + iy$ I get the following:
$$
 |e^{z^2}|
 = |e^{x^2 - y^2 + 2iy}|
 = |e^{x^2 - y^2}||e^{2iy}|
 = e^{x^2 - y^2}
 \leq e^4
$$
and
$$
 |4 \sin(z)|
 \leq 2(|e^{iz}| + |e^{-iz}|)
 = 2(e^{-y} + e^y)
 \leq 2(e^0 + e^2)
 = 2(1 + e^2)
$$

So as an answer I have an upper estimate of $e^4 + 2e^2 + 2$ using the triangle inequality but I'm not confident of my answer at all really, especially my answer for $|4 \sin(z)|$  Any help would be very kind and greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks right to me.

Comment: I wasn't sure about 2(e−y+ey)≤2(e0+e2)... would the RHS of this inequality not be 2(e-2+e2)?

Comment: The estimate is okay, but we need some reasoning: Of the two arguments $-y$ and $y$ one of them has to be $\geq 0$ and one has to be $\leq 0$, and both are $\leq 2$. If $y \geq 0$ and $-y \leq 0$ then $e^{-y} \leq e^0$ and $e^y \leq e^2$, and if $y \leq 0$ and $-y \geq 0$ then $e^{-y} \leq e^2$ and $e^y \leq e^0$. So the estimate holds. But it might be easier to just use that $y,-y \leq 2$ and thus $e^{-y} + e^y \leq 2e^2$.

Comment: okay, thanks for your help.